# How to import "File" in Golang?

Tags: file, go, import

I have a simple package the wraps a set of files that are generated together, sort of like a log but serving a different purpose, and I want to have a struct that keeps those files, so I have some code like the following, but I get compilation errors about File being undefined.

```golang
package foo

import "os"

type stuff struct {
   f1 *File  // I get errors that File isn't defined
   f2 *File
}
 
Open() stuff {
   var mine stuff
   mine.f1 = os.Open("f1")
   mine.f2 = os.Open("f2")
   return mine
}
```

Now, as far as I can tell the `os` package defines a `File` type.  What do I need to do to `import` that correctly?

All the Golang tutorials use Files locally without declaring them.  I need a file (handle) that persists over a series of calls.

Answer (score 0):

the type should contain package name `os.File`

```
type stuff struct {
    f1 *os.File 
    f2 *os.File
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Access it as `os.File` rather than just `File`

```
package foo

import "os"

type stuff struct {
    f1 *os.File
    f2 *os.File
}

func Open() stuff {
    var mine stuff
    var err error
    mine.f1, err = os.Open("f1")
    if err != nil {
        // handle error 
    }
    mine.f2, err = os.Open("f2")
    if err != nil {
        // handle error 
    }
    return mine
}
```